# Macbook Pro 14,1 Issues (all noticed so far)

Tags: sound, 22.04, bluetooth, webcam, macbook-pro

I fee like there has to be some simple issue related to all of these so I'm dropping a massive issue question for using Ubuntu 22.04 on a 2017 Macbook Pro 14,1.  The only issue I seem to not really have is at least the Wi-Fi is working!

I've tried several steps for troubleshooting audio and bluetooth and nothing is really going right.  I noticed along my troubleshooting some of the corrective actions included adding # symbols in source code...so I'm hoping someone can point me in a direction to fixing something like that because none of the apt install/update etc have had any luck.

Scope of the problem: several features on this machine are not working as intended.

2017 MacbookPro 14,1 Model: A1708
256GB, 8 GB Ram
2.3GHz i5 Intel core

all issues using Ubuntu 22.04

1. usb detection including thumb drive/ehd (detected if plugged in upon power up - format is macOS journaled and exFAT)
2. bluetooth not connecting
3. audio not working on internal speakers
4. unabe to import photos from iphone/iphone only shows up documents
5. webcam not detected in "cheese"

Details per problem:

1. I am only able to mount EHD/USB drives (scandisk USB-C, Toshiba 4TB USB) when they are plugged in before i power on the laptop.  If I power on, then plug in and try lsusb they are not recognized.  No problem, i can live with it for now...but i feel it shouldn't be so uncooperative.
2. bluetooth: simply put, i cannot toggle on and detect bluetooth devices.  I tried a few things and seem to fix a firmware problem using lsb_release -a when no lsb module was seen.  so i updated using sudo apt-get install lsb-core.  I even ran a script from another article.  I think i have still not overcome fail to init hci0.
3. audio: I only have dummy output, i can control the volume slider using the keyboard icon but no change...i simply do not have audio from the laptops internal speakers.  I cannot even get audio from headphones using the 1/8" jack.  The only way i was able to use sound was to plug in a focusrite audio interface and plug in headphones to that.  I checked alsamixer...I only have S/PDIF0, 1, and 2 they are set to 00 and i can select m to mute but not update the output.  I tried updating pulseaudio and it has no affect.
4. use with iPhone: when I plug in my iPhone 12 it is deteced as "documents iphone" and i cannot see files on it.  So I am unable to import photos let alone add music to it.
5. webcam not detected: that's straight forward.  I open the app cheese and it just doesn't detect the hardware.

These are all issues from after installing Ubuntu 22.04 using a ScanDisk USB-C that I flashed Ubuntu.iso onto using balena etcher.  I have done updates but I'm hoping someone can come out with some guidance on correcting something in the source code or maybe i missed a step I was supposed to check after the install.

Comment: sound: https://github.com/davidjo/snd_hda_macbookpro . For other issues, this post has some pointers https://victorleungtw.medium.com/install-ubuntu-20-04-lts-on-macbookpro14-1-9f1b6afde43d Please let us know how it goes